# Python .split() on a string on every splittable token bar whitespace, but ignore some specific strings

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am looking to split a sentence into tokens, but ignore 2 specific strings and also ignore spaces.

For example:

`GNI per capita ; PPP -LRB- US dollar -RRB- in LOCATION_SLOT was last measured at NUMBER_SLOT in 2011 , according to the World Bank .`

Should be split into `[GNI,per,capita,;,PPP,-,LRB,-,US,dollar,-,RRB,-,in, LOCATION_SLOT,was,last,measured,at,NUMBER_SLOT,in,2011,,,according,to, the, World,Bank,.,]`.

I do not want `LOCATION_SLOT` or `NUMBER_SLOT` to be split, for example the former into `[LOCATION,_,SLOT]`. But I do want to account for dots.

My current function which only allows character based words but is removing numbers and things like `;,,,:` etc is here - I don't want it to remove these:

```
def sentence_to_words(sentence,remove_stopwords=False):
    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z| LOCATION_SLOT | NUMBER_SLOT]", " ", sentence)
    words = letters_only.lower().split() 
    if remove_stopwords:
            stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
            words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]
    return(words)
```

This generates these tokens:

`gni per capita ppp lrb us dollar rrb location_slot last measured number_slot according world bank`

Comment: on one hand you are saying that there is a space before and after `;`, but you are not considering space in `-` just after `RRB`

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, the spaces in my split, as they are not in between `,`, are not actually spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` and strip the spaces from starting and ending

```
>>> [x.strip() for x in re.findall('\s*(\w+|\W+)', line)]
#['GNI', 'per', 'capita', ';', 'PPP', '-', 'LRB', '-', 'US', 'dollar', '-', 'RRB', '-', 'in', 'LOCATION_SLOT', 'was', 'last', 'measured', 'at', 'NUMBER_SLOT', 'in', '2011', ',', 'according', 'to', 'the', 'World', 'Bank', '.']
```

*Regex Explanation*

```
> \w matches word character [A-Za-z0-9_].
> \W is negation of \w. i.e. it matches anything except word character.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use split

```
>>> x = "GNI per capita ; PPP -LRB- US dollar -RRB- in LOCATION_SLOT was last measured at NUMBER_SLOT in 2011 , according to the World Bank ."
>>>
>>> x.split()
['GNI', 'per', 'capita', ';', 'PPP', '-LRB-', 'US', 'dollar', '-RRB-', 'in', 'LOCATION_SLOT', 'was', 'last', 'measured', 'at', 'NUMBER_SLOT', 'in', '2011', ',', 'according', 'to', 'the', 'World', 'Bank', '.']
```

To remove the - around -LBR- do this:

```
>>> z = [y.strip('-') for y in x]
>>> z
['GNI', 'per', 'capita', ';', 'PPP', 'LRB', 'US', 'dollar', 'RRB', 'in', 'LOCATION_SLOT', 'was', 'last', 'measured', 'at', 'NUMBER_SLOT', 'in', '2011', ',', 'according', 'to', 'the', 'World', 'Bank', '.']
>>>
```

If you want to keep the dashes:

```
>>> y = []
>>> for item in x:
...   if item.startswith('-') and item.endswith('-'):
...     y.append(',')
...     y.append(item.strip('-'))
...     y.append('-')
...   else:
...     y.append(item)
...
```

Comment: Ah how silly. I didn't know that split() doesn't split on `_`.

Comment: Question though, here we don't split `-RRB-` into 3 parts, how would I include that in?

Comment: second one will remove `-` which is not what OP wants